# Python beautiful soup select text

Tags: python, html-parsing, beautifulsoup

The following is an example of the HTML code I want to parse:

```
<html>
<body>
<td style="PADDING-LEFT:  5px"bgcolor="ffffff" class="style8"> Example BLAB BLAB BLAB </td>
<td style="PADDING-LEFT:  5px"bgcolor="ffffff" class="style8"> BLAB BLAB BLAB </td>
<td style="PADDING-LEFT:  5px"bgcolor="ffffff" class="style8"> BLAB BLAB BLAB </td>
<td style="PADDING-LEFT:  5px"bgcolor="ffffff" class="style8"> BLAB BLAB BLAB </td>
</body>
</html>
```

I am using beautiful soup to parse the HTML code by selecting style8 as follows (where html reads the result of my http request):

```
html = result.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

content = soup.select('.style8')
```

In this example, the `content` variable returns a list of 4 Tags. I want to check the `content.text`, which contains the text of each `style8` class, for each item in the list if it contains `Example` and appends that to a variable. If it proceeds through the entire list and `Example` does not occur within the list, it then appends `Not present` to the variable.

I have got the following so far:

```
foo = []

for i, tag in enumerate(content):
    if content[i].text == 'Example':
        foo.append('Example')
        break
    else:
        continue
```

This will only append `Example` to `foo` if it occurs, however it will not append `Not Present` if it does not occur within the entire list.

Any method of doing so is appreciated, or better way of searching the entire results to check if a string is present would be great

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to check whether it was found or not, you could use a simple boolean flag as follow :

```
foo = []
found = False
for i, tag in enumerate(content):
    if content[i].text == 'Example':
        found = True
        foo.append('Example')
        break
    else:
        continue
if not found:
    foo.append('Not Example')
```

If I get what you want, this may be a simple approach, though the solution of alecxe looks amazing.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `find_all()` to find all `td` elements with `class='style8'` and use list comprehension to construct the `foo` list:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


html = """<html>
<body>
<td style="PADDING-LEFT:  5px"bgcolor="ffffff" class="style8"> Example BLAB BLAB BLAB </td>
<td style="PADDING-LEFT:  5px"bgcolor="ffffff" class="style8"> BLAB BLAB BLAB </td>
<td style="PADDING-LEFT:  5px"bgcolor="ffffff" class="style8"> BLAB BLAB BLAB </td>
<td style="PADDING-LEFT:  5px"bgcolor="ffffff" class="style8"> BLAB BLAB BLAB </td>
</body>
</html>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

foo = ["Example" if "Example" in node.text else "Not Present" 
       for node in soup.find_all('td', {'class': 'style8'})]
print foo
```

prints:

```
['Example', 'Not Present', 'Not Present', 'Not Present']
```